# OpenGL ES 2D Drawing Performance Estimation

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es, drawing, 2d

I've been confronted with the extremely bad drawing Performance of Quartz/Core Graphics.

I don't believe its bad in every scenario, but in my occasion, where i need to redraw something like 3000 short lines frequently, it performs super bad.

Since the Modal (of MVC) is fixed I can not change how it spits out the data (if I could, i would have followed the advice, to only draw the changes, so the lines dont have to be redrawn every frame).

So as a conclusion I am considering using opengl for that purpose and I would like to ask u (experienced) guys for an estimation of how well it could work using opengl, before starting to work into that topic, as it seems by far more difficult
than Quartz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly see a speed performance lift from OpenGL over Quartz, however remember that whereas Quartz uses point to point drawing, OpenGL is based on the use of vertices and vertices points (essentially co-ordinates). You may find you need to do some mid-weight parsing work on your existing data source to re-work it into this vertices point system.

Also keep in mind that drawing text on top of an OpenGL ES object is a tricky task - it can be done (ironically) by using Quartz to generate an image, and then using this image as a texture.

I'd definitely recommend using OpenGL Kit as it will make life a bit easier for you as a beginner to OpenGL. Ray Wenderlich has an excellent starting point tutorial here :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5223/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-1

Comment: thanks for your answer! I will look at OpenGL Kit, it would be nice, if you could give an estimation on how many frames, each containing around 3000 short lines, could be drawn per second by OpenGL

Comment: It depends a lot on what device you are running it on and its processor, but I'd say on iPad 2 onwards you are looking at at least 30fps.

Comment: thanks so much! There is hope that my app is able to run fluently, again!